# How to display currency with humanized_money_with_symbol method? Like USD$ 100

Tags: ruby-on-rails, money-rails

I would like to `humanized_money_with_symbol` method to return something like `USD$ 100`, not only `$ 100`. Also I would like to do it only when currency symbol is `$`, we want to let users know when `$` is USD and when AUD.

Answer (score 1):

Never used [MoneyRails](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails) but it [looks like](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails/blob/master/lib/money-rails/helpers/action_view_extension.rb) `humanized_money_with_symbol` just calls `humanized_money` merging in `symbol: true` to the parameters you passed it.

That helper then in turn calls `format` on the money object passed in, passing in the options you specified. In the [Money](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money) gem, you can pass in a `:symbol` to render the currency with such as

```
m = Money.new('123', :gbp) # => #<Money fractional:123 currency:GBP>
m.format( symbol: m.currency.to_s + ' ') # => "GBP 1.23"
```

So, if you call

```
humanized_money(Money.new('123', :usd), symbol: 'USD $')
# => "USD $1.23"
```

You could then set up a helper method in your application, to avoid always having to pass that symbol in such as:

```
def render_custom_currency(value, options = {})
  value.currency.iso_code == "USD" ? humanized_money(value, options.merge(symbol: 'USD $')) : humanized_money(value, options.merge(symbol: true))
end
```

that should get you what you're wanting to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the USD configuration in `initializers/money.rb` to display "USD" as part of the symbol:

```
MoneyRails.configure do |config|
  config.register_currency = {
    "priority": 2,
    "iso_code": "USD",
    "name": "United States Dollar",
    "symbol": "USD $",
    "subunit": "Cent",
    "subunit_to_unit": 100,
    "symbol_first": true,
    "decimal_mark": ".",
    "thousands_separator": ",",
  }
end
```

Restart the server and you should see "USD $100". I don't use multiple currencies but this should leave your other currencies displayed as normal.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I used built-in in MoneyRails gem option `disambiguate: true`.

To use it you call method like below:

```rb
humanized_money_with_symbol(value, disambiguate: true)
```

Some examples how it works are [here](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money/blob/290fb35d631efca16d021af5fd0b1088313897c2/lib/money/money/formatting.rb#L159-L166)